# How can I add 1-100 numbers to picker view programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I created a UIPickerView manually with three components. I want to display numbers from 1 to 100 in component1. How can I do it programmatically?

Answer (score 8):

I guess you have implemented the methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 3;
}
```

and

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{

    if (component == 1 )
    {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(row+1)];
    }

    return @"";//required elements
}
```

Comment: this is the most sensible answer, but `row` is zero-indexed, so you want to offset by one: `return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row + 1]`

Answer (score 4):

in .h file

```
NSMutableArray *data ;
```

--

```
data = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=1; i<=100; i++){
     [data addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
}
```

// this will add 1-100 values in your array (data)
Then Implement UIPickerViewDelegate

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {

return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

return [data count];
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return [data objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use below code it wil help you

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if(component==1)
    return 100;
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component==1)
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",row+1];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick answer (just passing through). Use an array for storing the values. Use some kind of loop to quickly add the values 1-1000. Use something like this to get the value:

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:   (NSInteger)component{
 return [component1Array objectAtIndex: row];
}
```